# Drivers for CH9102X serial port chip

Tags: esp8266, esp32

Some ESP-family cheap boards manufacturers had recently moved to CH9102X serial port chip (from CP2102), and it seems the drivers for CH9102X are hard to find.

Where can I download them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be found on manufacturer's website: http://www.wch.cn/search?q=CH9102&t=downloads

Please note, that some drivers' downloading pages are only available in Chinese, so make sure you open Chinese (not English) site version.

Windows CDC driver: http://www.wch.cn/downloads/CH343CDC_ZIP.html

Windows SER driver: http://www.wch.cn/downloads/CH343SER_ZIP.html

MacOS driver: http://www.wch.cn/downloads/CH34XSER_MAC_ZIP.html

P.S. For Windows 7 x64 I recommend using the first one (CDC). SER driver didn't work for me because of signing issues.

Comment: Did you ask this question just so that you could answer it?

Comment: Exactly. See also: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/